# Geometry path dependency processing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have Custom Control Library and do icon "control". Also i have PathGeometry figures accessible by x:Key. So as example input is IconName="Icon_Close" in MainWindow.xaml, i want to equate IconName="Icon_Close" with PathGeometry figure which x:Key equals to "Icon_Close" and show icon

But i have no ideas how to process/convert it...

Icon.xaml (Generic)

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="Icon_Close" Figures="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="Icon_WndMinimize" Figures="M19,13H5V11H19V13Z"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="Icon_WndMaximize" Figures="M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Icon}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Icon}">
                <Viewbox Height="{TemplateBinding IconHeight}"
                         Width="Auto">
                    <Canvas Height="24"
                            Width="24">
                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding IconColor}"
                              Data="{TemplateBinding IconName}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Icon.cs

```
public class Icon : Control
{  
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconName", typeof(Geometry), typeof(Icon),
            new PropertyMetadata(Geometry.Empty));
    public Geometry IconName
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(IconNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconNameProperty, value); }
    }

    static Icon()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Icon), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Icon)));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<uiLib:Icon IconHeight="100"
            IconColor="White"
            IconName="Icon_Close"/>
```

Comment: I don't follow the purpose of your control. The markup seems overcomplicated as well. Why aren't you simply using a  path with data set as a geometry and stretch fill?

Comment: @Andy I want to change icons dynamically in mvvm pattern. Not convenient to use path with data in xaml markup when dynamically icons can be up to 15. I wanted to do something like ready icon pack library but just my own. Download ready library is easiest way but i want get some experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead use a Path you can do everything your control appears to be doing with the exception of setting the data with your path.

A Path can stretch so there's no point in the viewbox.

You don't need to put a path in a canvas either, it inherits from frameworkelement.

Here's an example path.

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource Musketeer}" 
      Height="18" 
      Stretch="Uniform" 
      Fill="Black"  
      Margin="4,0,0,0" />
```

Make the height 30 and the musketeer shaped geometry would be 30 px high and retain the proportions of the geometry.

All you need is a dependency property with an onChange handler that finds that geometry out resources.

Path is sealed so you can't extend it, but you could add an attached dependency property like this:

```
public class Attacher : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
               GeometryProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "Geometry", typeof(string), typeof(Attacher), new PropertyMetadata("", GeometryChanged));

    private static void GeometryChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var path = d as Path;
        if (path == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var geom = path.TryFindResource(e.NewValue.ToString()) as Geometry;
        if (geom is Geometry)
        {
            path.Data = geom;
        }
    }
    public static string GetGeometry(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(GeometryProperty);
    }
    public static void SetGeometry(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(GeometryProperty, value);
    }
}
```

You can probably think of a better name than attacher.

The way that works is it attaches the dependency property to the path.

Usage:

```
    <Path Fill="Red"
          Stretch="Fill"
          local:Attacher.Geometry="BeeIcon"
          />
```

local is an xmlns reference to the clr namespace the attacher is in.

My beeicon is:

```
<Geometry x:Key="BeeIcon">
    M15.551045,25.144995L16.748029,25.144995 16.249038,28.637C16.249038,28.637,15.651051,25.543997,15.551045,25.144995z M21.237988,21.152998L21.437999,21.152998C20.340014,23.049002 18.345033,24.247 16.150041,24.247 13.95404,24.247 11.959059,23.049002 10.861073,21.252997L10.96108,21.252997C15.351034,22.550002,18.943021,21.952002,21.237988,21.152998z M21.337995,14.967002L21.437999,15.067001C21.936988,15.965002,22.235997,16.962996,22.235997,18.160002L22.235997,18.658995 22.036994,18.759001C17.746037,20.653998,12.458048,19.556998,10.16308,18.858L10.063075,18.858 10.063075,18.759001 10.063075,18.160002C10.063075,17.162001,10.263086,16.164,10.761068,15.365997L10.861073,15.365997C16.150041,17.560996,20.141011,15.665,21.337995,14.967002z M16.150041,12.072998C17.746037,12.072998,19.243007,12.671997,20.340014,13.769996L20.44002,13.869003 20.340014,13.869003C17.247018,15.365997 13.356052,14.568 11.560075,14.069 12.657052,12.772003 14.353055,12.072998 16.150041,12.072998z M27.523957,8.3820033C28.821952,8.3820033 29.918929,8.6809992 30.517924,9.3789973 32.91293,12.072998 32.712918,16.663001 27.623963,15.566001 22.534976,14.468002 18.345033,11.674003 17.646031,10.875999L19.043027,10.376998C19.143001,10.376998,23.93197,8.3820033,27.523957,8.3820033z M4.5751051,8.3820033C8.0670862,8.3820033,12.957068,10.376998,12.957068,10.376998L14.353055,10.875999C13.655062,11.674003 9.4640798,14.468002 4.3751249,15.566001 -0.71285403,16.663001 -0.91286493,12.072998 1.4821384,9.3789973 2.1801321,8.5810008 3.2781166,8.3820033 4.5751051,8.3820033z M16.150041,3.2929987C18.145022,3.292999 19.64202,4.8889994 19.64202,6.7850031 19.64202,8.7809977 18.045016,10.277 16.150041,10.277 14.154051,10.277 12.657052,8.6809992 12.657052,6.7850031 12.557047,4.8889994 14.154051,3.292999 16.150041,3.2929987z M12.757057,1.0979993L13.056066,1.5960004 12.957068,1.5960004C12.857062,1.5960005 12.657052,1.4970015 12.557047,1.3970029 12.557047,1.2969969 12.657052,1.0979994 12.757057,1.0979993z M19.542016,9.6861186E-11C19.741996,-6.1625087E-08 19.840995,-6.1625087E-08 20.041005,0.099998488 20.839003,0.399002 21.237988,1.2969969 20.839003,2.0950009 20.44002,3.093002 19.342006,3.5920026 18.345033,3.1930003L18.943021,1.996002 19.043027,1.996002C19.44201,2.0950009 19.840995,1.8960036 19.940999,1.4970014 20.041005,1.1969984 19.940999,0.79800405 19.64202,0.69799812 19.342006,0.59899892 19.143001,0.69799794 18.943021,0.99800076 18.856397,1.1721237 18.921365,1.3470176 19.072932,1.4550116L19.129043,1.4886372 19.44201,1.0979993C19.542016,1.1969984 19.64202,1.2969969 19.542016,1.3970029 19.44201,1.4970015 19.342006,1.5960005 19.143001,1.5960004L19.103326,1.5960004 18.943021,1.996002C18.444032,1.7959975 18.245027,1.1969984 18.444032,0.69799812 18.644011,0.29900353 19.043027,-6.1625087E-08 19.542016,9.6861186E-11z M12.757057,9.6861186E-11C13.256047,-6.1625087E-08 13.655062,0.29900353 13.855041,0.79800428 14.054046,1.2969969 13.855041,1.8960036 13.356052,2.0950009L13.056066,1.5960004C13.256047,1.4970015 13.356052,1.2969969 13.256047,1.0979993 13.156041,0.79800405 12.857062,0.69799794 12.557047,0.79800428 12.258068,0.89800252 12.059064,1.2969969 12.258068,1.5960004 12.458048,1.996002 12.857062,2.1949994 13.156041,2.0950009L13.256047,2.0950009 13.855041,3.1930003C12.857062,3.5920026 11.759047,3.093002 11.360063,2.0950009 11.061054,1.2969969 11.460069,0.399002 12.158062,0.099998488 12.358073,-6.1625087E-08 12.557047,-6.1625087E-08 12.757057,9.6861186E-11z
</Geometry>
```

But it also works fine with your style of defining streamgeometries.

```
    <Path Fill="Red"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          Height="32"
          local:Attacher.Geometry="Icon_Close"
          />
```

You can then bind fill, stroke, height, stretch etc and a string for the geometry.